# pm2 list command displaying badly formatted results

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, pm2

I've been playing around with [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) for the first time on a remote Ubuntu instance.

It seems to be running fine but when I list the running processes using `pm2 list` the formatting of the table is a bit messed up.

[image]

It's not a big deal as everything appears to be working but was just wondering why the display is showing like this.

This is Ubuntu 14.04 with node 0.10.25 connecting over Putty

Any ideas?

Comment: With SecureCRT: Select Options -> Session Options -> Terminal -> Appearence -> Character encoding -> select: UTF-8. Hope help others like me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely an issue with your Putty character encoding.  Please have a look at [this Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/475930/272579) answer and see if it fixes things for you.

Comment: indeed it was! char set needed setting to UTF-8 in putty settings :) thx

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it!